# How do I get that Chris Stapleton Tennessee Whiskey Electric Guitar intro guitar sound?

Tags: electric-guitar

[Tennessee Whiskey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zAThXFOy2c&loop=0) I Have a EPIPHONE  Joe Pass EMPEROR II Electric and a CUBE 20x Amp. I been told its because the GUITAR IS A Jazz guitar.

[Tennessee Whiskey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zAThXFOy2c&loop=0)

[SOLO SOUND IM SEEKING](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpW33OKcFDQ&start=07:28&end=07:47&loop=10)

Comment: It would be helpful to have a text description of the sound. Links have a tendency to go bad, and then the question loses at least some of its meaning.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid questions like this, about matching a certain sound, are not [covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Feel free to edit this question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

A hollow body guitar like yours is considered to be preferable for jazz because of its acoustic properties combined with magnetic guitar pickups. However Ted Nugent proved you can play rock on what is considered a jazz guitar. He uses Gibson Byrdland hollow body guitars a lot. Electronically his guitar and yours are similar to a Gibson Les Paul, a guitar that can be a real screamer.

One important thing is the setup. If you set it up for jazz with heavy flat wound strings and medium to high action then jazz is going to be what it does best. It will have a fat dark sound and bending strings more than a semitone will be a real chore. If you set it up for pop/rock with lighter gauge round wound strings it won’t sound as much like a jazz box but will allow you to get a more contemporary sound and bend strings more easily.

As for other elements of the sound, use the bridge pickup with the volume and tone all the way up. Experiment with the various settings on the amp for the overdrive/distortion sound that you think matches his sound. I would start with the overdrive setting, the gain around 6 or 7 and the master volume set according to how loud you want to play. From there try slight tweaks to the gain for more or less overdrive and distortion to find what works for you. There is some reverb used as well.

The bottom of line is you have to decide whether setting up your guitar in this manner will suit most or all your needs or not. If you’re mostly playing jazz, you may want to consider buying a solid or semi-hollow body guitar to do this type of playing. One compromise would be a set or roundwound strings that are heavier than 9’s or 10’s but not as heavy as a jazz set.